# Finding out a words prefix in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a database with common english words. I want to find the prefix of each of these words and rate the word based on the prefix. I have 3 catorgoties for the rating system, postive, neutral, and negative. I turned each catorgory into an array. Right now I am spliting each word apart and want to compair that to each list to see where the word falls.

This is the code I have so far. import csv

```
negativePrefix = ['un', 'in', 'im','il','ir','non', 'mis','mal','dis','anti','de','under', 'semi', 'mini', 'ex', 'sub', 'infra']

postivePrefix = ['re', 'over', 'equi', 'micro','macro','mega','extra','prime', 'post','retro', 'bi','multi','pro','auto','co','con']

neutralPrefix = ['inter', 'super', 'super','peri', 'ante', 'pre','semi', 'mono', 'tri','quad','penta','hex','sept','oct','dec']

postive = 2
neutral = 1
negative = 0

path = r'/Users/Valerie/Desktop/ClassCoding/gdi/javascript_2/common_words_Update_2.csv'
fileName = 'common_words_Update_2'
  with open(path, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        word = ' '.join(''.join(row)) 
        print word
        # check to see if the word matches one of the arrays
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for row in reader:
    for word in row:
        if any([word.startswith(w) for w in negativePrefix]):
            print("{} is negative!".format(word))
        elif any([word.startswith(w) for w in postivePrefix]):
            print("{} is positive!".format(word))
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if any(word.startswith(prefix) for prefix in negativePrefix):
   ...
elif any(word.startswith(prefix) for prefix in posativePrefix):
   ...
elif any(word.startswith(prefix) for prefix in neutralPrefix):
  ...
```

Comment: So simple! Thank you!